# MongoDB Text Index Unsupported Language

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a large database of Greek Tweets stored in a mongodb database.

> (3M Tweets arround 30GB of storage).

I have created a text index on the text and an ordered index on the timestamp fields. However, I found that MongoDB does not support the Greek language for text indexing thus  text queries in the Greek language are relativelly slow. How can I face that issue and create an inverted index also for the greek documents?

Comment: good [article](http://ngsiolei.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-inverted-index-in-mongodb.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use solr to built you index rather than mongodb , it has lot of feature to support multi-lingual search .

Answer (score 0):

I have just found that if I select as language none according to the documentation a simple inverted index using tokenization will be created.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#text-search-languages

> If you specify a language value of "none", then the text search uses
>   simple tokenization with no list of stop words and no stemming